# First file gets selected last

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, sequence

So I have an Image Sequence in a folder and I want to rename them to Image_1 Image_2 ect

```
set /a Index=0

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%i in (*.png) do ( 
    rename "%%i" "Image_!Index!.png"
    set /a Index+=1
)
```

I'm running this code and it works fine but there's 1 problem.
For some reason, the first image in the folder get renamed last, so they all rename fine but then the first image becomes the last one

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

I looked this up but couldn't find any solution

Comment: What are the filenames before they are renamed?

Comment: IMG_26069-art-scale-2_00x.png and the numbers go up so next is IMG_26070-art-scale-2_00x.png ect

Comment: Try `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /on *.png') do (` or `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /on "d:\directory name\*.png"') do (` which creates a filename list in memory, then processes the list.

Comment: This made it even more random

Is there a way to like, find the last file in a folder and rename it?
I can just change to ```Index=1``` so the first image will be +1 so 2, and just rename the last image to Image_1.
Cause i really can't find a solution for this...
I tried renaming all the files to 1,2,3,4,5 cause i thought maybe there's a problem with the naming and it makes it random as well, just like using ```for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /on *.png') do (```

Comment: Doesn't have to be the last file, could just be the file with the largest suffix,
Image_"Biggest Number".png

Comment: You haven't defined what you interpret as the first, or any order for your files. Your question talks about the first in a folder, but your code is for every folder in a tree. Your problem requires much more clarification. Please [Edit] your post to make things perfectly clear, preferably with actual before and after trees. Your main problem however, is you are using `for /r`. Please change it to ```For /F "Delims=" %%i in ('Dir *.png /A:-D /B /O:N /S')```

Comment: 1- Doesn't work
2- I think i'm crystal clear, i just wanna rename all the images in a folder to Image_1 Image_2 ect, they're already sorted by name, but the first image in the folder, gets named last. Not sure how more clear I can be

So I have the first image in the folder called Image_26069-art-scale-2_00x.png and the last one is called Image_26083-art-scale-2_00x.png
When I run the above script it renames them all find, in order
But Image_26069-art-scale-2_00x.png gets renamed last, it becomes Image_15 when it supposed to be Image_1 

If that's not clear for you then I don't know man

Comment: You're wrong! Read your question, where's the order/first defined? When you use `for /r`, against all `.png` files, the files are enumerated and renamed one at a time. There is nothing to stop a renamed .png file from being enumerated again. (Your first file would be `Image0.png`. Does that exist? Or was it re-enumerated, and therefore renamed again?) Additionally, whilst it may often look like a standard `for` glob is alphabetical, that's only coincidental, and never guaranteed. `For /F` using `Dir` and the `/O:N` option completes enumeration before `Do` and ensures alphabetical name sorting.

Comment: Filtering the files with `dir IMG_*.jpg` helps.